# Switching from coroutines(kotlin) to isolates(dart)

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart, kotlin-coroutines

I have an Android app made using Flutter.
Currently, most of the business logic runs on Android native Kotlin, but I love Dart so I am considering moving a lot of the logic to Flutter.
Is there any concern about converting Kotlin's coroutines to Dart's isolate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no general concerns that I'm aware of. Although there are some points that you need to consider before doing the change.

- The concurrency paradigm changes from multithread to single thread. This means that you should not think of changing coroutines to isolates, since you will not be using isolates so often or for the same purposes as coroutines.
- Isolates are used for "extreme/unique" cases, if you want to perform a long running operation, you normally shouldn't opt out for an isolate, you should perform that with the simple async/await.
- It's simpler to use async/await since you don't have to worry about resource allocations or race conditions, but at the same time it allows you to do "dirtier" things, to the responsability is on you.
- Last thought on Isolates: they are a separate process so communication between isolates is only done through messages, so basic data should be passed between them and that could give you some headaches if you want to return some big data. (Of course everything is possible with serialization)

Hope this helps you to choose, if not, feel free to comment and we can discuss this further.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sergio Pardo,  Why not long running operation shouldn't opt out for an isolate? Is it because of humans error?

Comment: @Taz It's mostly because it's an overkill. To extrapolate what it would mean to use isolates for long running tasks to android, it would be like to launch another application to perform such task and later on give me an answer. An Isolate is not only a different thread, it's a separate process with different resource allocation

Comment: `async-await` doesn't provide parallelism by itself. If we want to execute long running operation we need to dispatch it to another thread for execution so that the Main(Ui) thread won't freeze. To run code in parallel Dart provides isolates. For simple long running computations can use `compute` function.